# Checking a toggled Button for a Quiz Game in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

First, sorry for my bad English! I'm absolutely new to SwiftUI and I tried to create a Quiz App with multiple Choices and multiple Answers. I created a Button with a ForEach to Display the possible answers. Now I want to select the correct Answer and tap the check Button to validate the chosen Answer. There can be more then 1 correct Answer.

I tried this function but its only return, if there are one or two

```
//MARK:- Funktionen
func checkAnswer() {
    if validateAnswer == quiz.correctAnswer {
        print("Richtig")
    } else {
        print("Falsch")
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to validate the chosen Answers with the correct answers. Can anyone help me?
Here is my Code:
QuizModel

```
struct Quiz: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var question: String
    var howManyAnswers: String
    var options: [PossibleAnswer]
    var correctAnswer: [String]
    var explain: String
}

extension Quiz: Equatable {}

struct PossibleAnswer : Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text : String
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var quiz: Quiz
    @State var isChecked:Bool = false
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false
    @State var validateAnswer: [String] = ["Antwort 3", "Antwort 4"]

    //MARK:- Answers
            VStack {
                ForEach(quiz.options) { answerOption in
                    QuizButtonView(isChecked: isChecked, title: answerOption.text)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(2.0)

                }
             
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                HStack {
                 //MARK:- Button Überprüfen & Zurück
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Ich gehe zurück")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Zurück")
                    })
                    Button(action: {
                        checkAnswer()
                        print("Ich überprüfe...")
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Überprüfen")
                    })
                    .padding(.leading, 200)
```

And my CheckButtonView

```
struct QuizButtonView: View {
    @State var isChecked:Bool = false
    var title:String
    
    func toggle(){
        isChecked.toggle()
        if self.isChecked == true {
            print("Antwort wurde ausgewählt")
        } else if self.isChecked == false {
            print("Antwort wurde wieder abgewählt")
        }
        
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: toggle) {
                HStack{
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square.fill": "square")
                }
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is directly related, but this question was about a similar sounding quiz. Maybe it is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497666/swiftui-manipulate-single-items-generated-from-for-in-loop/

Comment: Thank you for your comment! :) This Case isn't helpful for my Case because I have for example 5 possible Answers and Checkboxes. Maybe one Question has to correctAnswers. After I selected my Answers I will tap on the Check Button. Than he should check the Answers.

Comment: @AleksandarNesovanovic can you share your base code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a state variable of an array of booleans:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private let quiz: Quiz
    @State private var userSelections: [Bool]

    init(quiz: Quiz) {
        self.quiz = quiz
        _userSelections = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, count: quiz.options.count))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<quiz.options.count) { index in
                QuizButtonView(isChecked: userSelections[index], title: quiz.options[index].text)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(2.0)
            }
        }
    }

    func checkAnswer() {
        let userSelectionTexts = Set(userSelections.enumerated().map({ quiz.options[$0.offset].text }))
        let correctAnswers = Set(quiz.correctAnswer)
        let isAllSelectionsTrue = userSelectionTexts == correctAnswers
        let isAllSelectionsFalse = userSelectionTexts.intersection(correctAnswers).isEmpty
        let isAnySelectionsTrue = !isAllSelectionsFalse
    }
}
```